# jboss remote deployment failure

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x, maven-cargo

I am getting error while deploying war file to remote jboss 5.1.ga server, but local deployment is working perfectly?

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <container>
            <containerId>jboss51x</containerId>
            <type>remote</type>
            <timeout>60000</timeout>
        </container>
        <configuration>
            <type>runtime</type>
            <properties>
                <cargo.hostname>127.0.0.1</cargo.hostname>
                <cargo.remote.username>admin</cargo.remote.username>
                <cargo.remote.password>admin</cargo.remote.password>
                <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
                <cargo.rmi.port>1099</cargo.rmi.port>
                <cargo.jboss.user>admin</cargo.jboss.user>
                <cargo.jboss.password>admin</cargo.jboss.password>
            </properties>
        </configuration>
        <deployables>
            <deployable>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                <type>war</type>
                <properties>
                    <context>/sample</context>
                </properties>
            </deployable>
        </deployables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**In client side Iam getting this error::**

```java
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.2.4:deploy (default-cli) on project sample: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.2.4:deploy failed: Cannot deploy deployable
 org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.deployable.JBossWAR[sample.war]: Remote action failed: null (java.io.IOException: Can not get connection to server. Problem establishing socket connection for InvokerLocator [socket://rohan_l/?]
) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

**In jboss server console :**

```java
8:37:02,156 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009
18:37:02,156 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221634)] Started in 35s:16ms
18:37:24,406 INFO  [DeployHandler] Handle stream, deploymentTarget: names=[sample.war], copyContent=true, description=file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/rohan_l/workspace/projects/sample/do_not_checkin/target/sample.war
18:37:29,937 WARN  [HDScanner] Scan failed
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error determining structure: sample.war
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.explicit.DeclaredStructure.determineStructure(DeclaredStructure.java:89)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.StructureDeployerWrapper.determineStructure(StructureDeployerWrapper.java:73)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.doDetermineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:196)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.determineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:221)
at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:77)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineStructure(MainDeployerImpl.java:1004)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineDeploymentContext(MainDeployerImpl.java:440)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:390)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:300)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.addDeployment(MainDeployerAdapter.java:86)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:344)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractExceptionHandler.handleZipEntriesInitException(AbstractExceptionHandler.java:39)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.helpers.NamesExceptionHandler.handleZipEntriesInitException(NamesExceptionHandler.java:63)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.ensureEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:626)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.checkIfModified(ZipEntryContext.java:773)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.getChild(ZipEntryContext.java:817)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.createChildHandler(ZipEntryHandler.java:191)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVirtualFileHandler.structuredFindChild(AbstractVirtualFileHandler.java:684)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.getChild(ZipEntryHandler.java:165)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.DelegatingHandler.getChild(DelegatingHandler.java:107)
at org.jboss.virtual.VirtualFile.getChild(VirtualFile.java:481)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.explicit.DeclaredStructure.determineStructure(DeclaredStructure.java:64)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipFileWrapper.ensureZipFile(ZipFileWrapper.java:175)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipFileWrapper.acquire(ZipFileWrapper.java:245)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.initEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:484)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.ensureEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:619)
... 28 more
18:45:34,171 INFO  [DeployHandler] Handle stream, deploymentTarget: names=[sample.war], copyContent=true, description=file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/rohan_l/workspace/projects/sample/do_not_checkin/target/sample.war
18:45:35,734 WARN  [HDScanner] Scan failed
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error determining structure: sample.war
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.explicit.DeclaredStructure.determineStructure(DeclaredStructure.java:89)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.StructureDeployerWrapper.determineStructure(StructureDeployerWrapper.java:73)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.doDetermineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:196)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.determineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:221)
at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:77)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineStructure(MainDeployerImpl.java:1004)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineDeploymentContext(MainDeployerImpl.java:440)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:390)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:300)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.addDeployment(MainDeployerAdapter.java:86)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:344)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractExceptionHandler.handleZipEntriesInitException(AbstractExceptionHandler.java:39)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.helpers.NamesExceptionHandler.handleZipEntriesInitException(NamesExceptionHandler.java:63)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.ensureEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:626)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.checkIfModified(ZipEntryContext.java:773)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.getChild(ZipEntryContext.java:817)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.createChildHandler(ZipEntryHandler.java:191)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVirtualFileHandler.structuredFindChild(AbstractVirtualFileHandler.java:684)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.getChild(ZipEntryHandler.java:165)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.DelegatingHandler.getChild(DelegatingHandler.java:107)
at org.jboss.virtual.VirtualFile.getChild(VirtualFile.java:481)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.explicit.DeclaredStructure.determineStructure(DeclaredStructure.java:64)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipFileWrapper.ensureZipFile(ZipFileWrapper.java:175)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipFileWrapper.acquire(ZipFileWrapper.java:245)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.initEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:484)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.ensureEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:619)
... 28 more
18:59:00,578 INFO  [DeployHandler] Handle stream, deploymentTarget: names=[sample.war], copyContent=true, description=file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/rohan_l/workspace/projects/sample/do_not_checkin/target/sample.war
18:59:01,000 WARN  [HDScanner] Scan failed
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error determining structure: sample.war
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.explicit.DeclaredStructure.determineStructure(DeclaredStructure.java:89)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.StructureDeployerWrapper.determineStructure(StructureDeployerWrapper.java:73)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.doDetermineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:196)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.determineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:221)
at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:77)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineStructure(MainDeployerImpl.java:1004)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineDeploymentContext(MainDeployerImpl.java:440)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:390)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:300)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.addDeployment(MainDeployerAdapter.java:86)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:344)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractExceptionHandler.handleZipEntriesInitException(AbstractExceptionHandler.java:39)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.helpers.NamesExceptionHandler.handleZipEntriesInitException(NamesExceptionHandler.java:63)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.ensureEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:626)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.checkIfModified(ZipEntryContext.java:773)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.getChild(ZipEntryContext.java:817)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.createChildHandler(ZipEntryHandler.java:191)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVirtualFileHandler.structuredFindChild(AbstractVirtualFileHandler.java:684)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.getChild(ZipEntryHandler.java:165)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.DelegatingHandler.getChild(DelegatingHandler.java:107)
at org.jboss.virtual.VirtualFile.getChild(VirtualFile.java:481)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.explicit.DeclaredStructure.determineStructure(DeclaredStructure.java:64)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipFileWrapper.ensureZipFile(ZipFileWrapper.java:175)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipFileWrapper.acquire(ZipFileWrapper.java:245)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.initEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:484)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.ensureEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:619)
... 28 more
19:03:37,312 INFO  [DeployHandler] Handle stream, deploymentTarget: names=[sample.war], copyContent=true, description=file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/rohan_l/workspace/projects/sample/do_not_checkin/target/sample.war
19:03:40,656 WARN  [HDScanner] Scan failed
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error determining structure: sample.war
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.explicit.DeclaredStructure.determineStructure(DeclaredStructure.java:89)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.StructureDeployerWrapper.determineStructure(StructureDeployerWrapper.java:73)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.doDetermineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:196)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.determineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:221)
at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:77)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineStructure(MainDeployerImpl.java:1004)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineDeploymentContext(MainDeployerImpl.java:440)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:390)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:300)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.addDeployment(MainDeployerAdapter.java:86)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:344)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractExceptionHandler.handleZipEntriesInitException(AbstractExceptionHandler.java:39)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.helpers.NamesExceptionHandler.handleZipEntriesInitException(NamesExceptionHandler.java:63)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.ensureEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:626)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.checkIfModified(ZipEntryContext.java:773)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.getChild(ZipEntryContext.java:817)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.createChildHandler(ZipEntryHandler.java:191)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVirtualFileHandler.structuredFindChild(AbstractVirtualFileHandler.java:684)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.getChild(ZipEntryHandler.java:165)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.DelegatingHandler.getChild(DelegatingHandler.java:107)
at org.jboss.virtual.VirtualFile.getChild(VirtualFile.java:481)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.explicit.DeclaredStructure.determineStructure(DeclaredStructure.java:64)
 ... 20 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipFileWrapper.ensureZipFile(ZipFileWrapper.java:175)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipFileWrapper.acquire(ZipFileWrapper.java:245)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.initEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:484)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.ensureEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:619)
... 28 more
```

Comment: "error in opening zip file". So check the EAR file. I have this sneaky suspicion that it gets damaged during the deployment.

Comment: iam deploying a war file, its generating 0kb war file in deployments dir

Comment: tada, cause found. Now to figure out why you get a 0k war file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JBoss5: Cannot deploy due to java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646322/jboss5-cannot-deploy-due-to-java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-fi)