# Jwrapper fails when making OSX file

Tags: java, macos, jwrapper

I hope this is the write place to ask about this.. I am trying to make a. Dmg file from my Java project using jwrapper and jre1.8.0_65 , it seems that it works for both windows and Linux, but when trying it for osx I get the following error : : 
    **********************************
    *          BUILD FAILED          *
    **********************************
    ** Reason: (see stacktrace below)

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:128)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:136)
```

Any ideas on why? Someone else had the same problem on a Mac (I am using Linux) their solution was rebooting, which does not work for me.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2821169/999516

Comment: I couldn't find anything that helped. I tried increasing the amount of files that my system can open to 9 gigs, and still nothing.